# When i try to capture a screenshot i get an "USB Storage may be in use" error. I can't install or use almost any app as well

Tags: usb-storage

First of all, I have a Galaxy Note 2. Hello, I've read more than an answer for this issue but none of them solved my problem. The problem is when I try to capture a screenshot it gives me an error message that says `"Unable to save the screenshot, USB storage may be in use"`. I can't also use any application. When I open any application it gives me the `"{Application name} has stopped"`

What is the solution? It ought to be mentioned that I've tried to wipe the cash partition but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try factory reset (save your important data before doing that)

Comment: @beeshyams No i didn't, but i think it will help. tho i solved the problem without doing that, it may help anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

After surfing the internet and trying more than a solution (i tried everything but the factory reset because I don't wanna do that) I discovered that this is a board problem. It's caused by many things. In my case, uninstalling Google Drive solved it. I got Link2SD and removed that app and that solved the problem. None of the tons of the solutions I read have mentioned that this problem may be caused because of some software need to be uninstalled. So, if you have the same problem and you reached this answer, try to play around your mobile phone and it will be solved. Because I and you have the same problem, but for different reasons.

If you are too lazy to do that, do a factory reset. It always helps.